# How do I get List of values from django form template to form.py Cleaned_data

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am actually try to post a list of values ['good','nice','happy'] to the backend.

I have following files in my django app.

```
models.py
class TagModel(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class BlogModel(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  tags = models.ManyToManyField(TagModel)
```

---

```
forms.py
class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
    'placeholder':_('Enter Blog Title'),
    'class' : 'form-control border-success'
}))
 blog_tags = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
    "name":"blog_tags"
}))

def clean_title(self):
    title = self.cleaned_data.get('title')
    print(title)
    return title

def clean_blog_tags(self):
    //this line does not get whole list of data
    tags = self.cleaned_data.get('blog_tags')
    print(tags) // problem is here
    return tags

class Meta:
    model = PostModel
    fields = ['title','blog_tags']
```

---

```
views.py
class create_blog(CreateView):
template_name = 'blogbackend/create_blog.html'
form_class=BlogForm

 def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(create_blog,self).get_form_kwargs()
    print(kwargs)
    return kwargs
```

---

Html Template
[image]

What happen on template is :-

1. I render the title field on the view
2. I added a JS code on Input box , which gets value a create a hidden input with name blog_tags

which is same as the filed name in forms.py file

After user submit the form

- I successfully receives the both input values title and blog_tags in my views.py file and successfully display on console with helper function get_form_kwargs()
- Data is look like this

  ```
   {'initial': {}, 'prefix': None, 'data': <QueryDict: 
   {'csrfmiddlewaretoken':  ['4Cm5mvGFv4skPJNTzRI8fKZKq9i7edQbwNmOgCPbDTtu8JQHqE5cd9rQLA8Kzhpu'],'title': ['first'],'blog_tags' : ['good','nice','happy']}>, 'instance':None}
  ```

Problem

- When I am trying to access the value inside function clean_blog_tags() it only prints list value "happy" on console

could anyone please help me to get whole list of values in clean function

Thanks
GS

Answer (score 0):

The `ChoiceField` is only to one choice if i remember. Is possible to change to `MultipleChoiceField` and in theory, this got work.

```py
blog_tags = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
    "name":"blog_tags"
}))
```

Comment: Hello @Eduardo_Oliveira thanks for comment, i tried this. However, this throws an error, Because when i submit the form it is redirecting me back and it now even run the function clean_blog_tags()